# Get subscriber id from in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have created a small app that has in-app subscription products.

I want to fetch the subscriber ID via API after the transaction has occurred. I searched extensively and found that this ID is available only in a report "Subscriber Report"

```
 Subscriber ID |  BigInt  |  The randomly generated Subscriber ID that is unique to each customer and developer
```

Is there a receipt response where this ID might be available? Can I map transaction id received in the receipt response to a subscriber?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, the subscriber ID in Apple "Subscriber Report" is internal so the information is actually anonymous.

Looking on the bright side in wwwdc 2017 apple announced that they will provide the subscription details for users as part of the receipt so you will be able to get all the information in the subscriber report for a given user. See the part on 'Voluntary Churn' in https://medium.com/joytunes/wwdc-2017-amazing-new-features-for-subscriptions-676662a7d993

Comment: Thanks! This is a good news. How do some of the bigger players on appstore manage the subscriber info today? Apple is the only one I am having a challenge with.

Comment: I honestly don't know. Apple just don't expose that data. You can tell today which user cancelled his subscription but information like when was the cancel and the cancel reason(billing issues/refund/...) appears only in the report and you canot trace it to a user. It is a real challenge and the news from wwwdc 2017 are encouraging and hopefully it will be able to rolled out soon.